# How to trigger Account Manager to add new account from application

Tags: android, account-management

I am trying to extend the [SampleSync](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/index.html) application. After I install the app, I can go to settings -> accounts & sync -> add account to add an account. However, if I want to check from my Application code and want to trigger AccountManager to add a new account directly, what should be the best way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25890770/3282461

[here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25890770/3282461) the full solution with code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25890770/3282461

see this... here is the full code and solution

Answer (score 5):

Ok, finally I got it working,

You can actually activate the AccountManager to add an account:

```
final AccountManager accountMgr = AccountManager.get(Main.this);
accountMgr.addAccount(Constants.ACCOUNT_TYPE, Constants.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE, null, null, Main.this, null, null);
```

Comment: What does the "Main.this" stand for!?

Comment: @chris, sorry I didn't put the full context. This code is in an anonymous inner class which sits in the Main.java class. From the inner class, you need to do Main.this to get a reference of the outer class. let me know if you need more details on this.